An SF story where an orangutan writes a book that is published
I read this short fiction (novelette rather than short story, I think) about 30 years ago, in a collection.
It takes place in a institution where apes (orangutans and chimpanzees, I don't remember gorillas) are taught many skills, in particular communication with humans. I know that in the real world apes do communicate with humans using a sign language, understand spoken human language, and even can type rather elaborate sentences using typewriters with keys bearing symbols representing nouns, verbs and even adjectives. But the SF aspect in this story is that one, particularly gifted orangutan, was able to read English and to type on a regular typewriter.
The orangutan was even able to write a story that was sent to an editor of children's books, who accepted it. Whether the editor knew it has been written by an ape, or accepted it even not knowing, I have forgotten.
IIRC, all the hullabaloo about that book resulted into a rather sad ending, but I have forgotten the details.

Her Furry Face by Leigh Kennedy. I read it in the anthology Alien Sex, which was published in 1990 so it could be the anthology you remember. The story itself was written in 1983.
The orangutan who write the book is Annie:

Annie rolled onto one side and lay propped on an elbow, staring at him. She was lovely. Fifteen years old, her fur was glossy and coppery, her small yellow eyes in the fleshy face expressive and intelligent. She started to rise up toward him, but turned toward the road.
The mail jeep was coming down the highway.
In a blurred movement, she set off at a four-point gallop down the half-mile drive toward the mailbox. Vernon swung down from his tree and followed, making a small groan.
Reluctant to go out in the sun, Douglas put down the tea and followed the apes down the drive. By the time he got near them, Annie was sitting with mail sorted between her toes, holding an opened letter in her hands. She looked up with an expression on her face that he’d never seen—it could have been fear, but it wasn’t.
She handed the letter to Vernon, who pestered her for it.
“Douglas,” she signed, “they want to buy my story.”

It ends badly when Douglas attempts to have sex with Annie. Another orangutan, Vernon, photographs the assault and gives the photos to the director of the institute ending Douglas's career and his (human) relationship.

"This is Annie, a fifteen-year-old orangutan, who has been a student with the school for five years. She graduated with honors from another "ape school” in Georgia before coming here. And now Annie has become a writer. Recently, she sold a story to a children’s magazine. The editor who bought the story didn’t know that Annie was an orangutan until after she had selected the story for publication.”

@DavidW So the editor did not know ! Thanks !

You can listen to the story on Clarkesworld (September 2014).
